# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.lang.Class, genericType=class java.lang.Class

Tags: java, jersey

I've been facing this issue with `Jersey` 2.25.1. It looks like I have all the dependencies and I am using `maven` so all the transitive dependencies should be there as well. Don't know how to fix it and based on our discussion these dependencies should be enough to support `xml` format. 
I added the code which breaks after debugging. Commented part was before updating the jersey. I think I am not implementing the post method correctly.

Code breaks here,

```
public IDocumentSet sendDocuments(IClientUserDto cu, IDocumentSet ds) throws ESignatureProviderException {

    logMethodStartDebug(cu, CLASS_NAME, "sendDocuments(IClientUserDto, IDocumentSet)");

    IDocumentSet set = null;

    List<DocumentContent> documentContent = new ArrayList<DocumentContent>();
    Envelope env = new Envelope();
    MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart();
    String token = null;
    String envId = null;
    String status = null;

    try {           
        List<IDocumentDto> dtos = loadDocuments(cu, ds);
        List<IDocument> docs = ds.getDocuments();
        dtos = validateDocs(docs, dtos);

        ISendDocumentsTransformerArgs args = new SendDocumentsTransformerArgs(cu);
        args.setDocuments(docs);
        args.setDocumentDtos(dtos);
        args.setCallbackConfiguration(getConfiguration().getCallback());
        args.setModuleConfiguration(getModuleConfiguration());

        ITransformer transformer = new SendDocumentsRESTTransformer();
        ITransformerResult result = transformer.transformRequest(args);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<Envelope, List<DocumentContent>> envDocMap = (Map<Envelope, List<DocumentContent>>) result.getResult();

        env = (Envelope) envDocMap.keySet().iterator().next();
        documentContent = (List<DocumentContent>) envDocMap.values().iterator().next();

        OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ESignatureJaxBContextFactory context = (ESignatureJaxBContextFactory) AppContext.getBean("jaxbContextFactory");
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = context.getMarshaller(Envelope.class);
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(env, outputStream);

        //System.out.println("Envelope : " + outputStream.toString());

        BodyPart bodyDoc = new BodyPart();
        bodyDoc.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);
        bodyDoc.getHeaders().add(DocusignRESTContants.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, DocusignRESTContants.FORM_DATA);
        bodyDoc.setEntity(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toString().getBytes()));
        multiPart.bodyPart(bodyDoc);

        for (DocumentContent docCont : documentContent ) {

            BodyPart bodyAttach = new BodyPart();
            bodyAttach.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
            bodyAttach.getHeaders().add(DocusignRESTContants.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "file; filename=" +docCont.getName()+ ".pdf; documentId=" + docCont.getDocumentId());
            bodyAttach.setEntity(docCont.getPdfBytes());
            multiPart.bodyPart( bodyAttach );
        }

        String accountId = DtoUtils.lookupClientUserVendorParam( ClientUserVendorParamConstants.DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID, cu.getClientUserVendor().getClientUserVendorParams() );
        String endpoint = ESignatureSpringUtil.getMessage( KeyConstants.DOCUSIGN_REST_ADDRESS );

        StringBuilder docSb = new StringBuilder();
        docSb.append( endpoint );
        docSb.append( DocusignRESTContants.ACCOUNTS );
        docSb.append( KeyConstants.URL_PATH_SEPARATOR );
        docSb.append( accountId );
        docSb.append( KeyConstants.URL_PATH_SEPARATOR );
        docSb.append( DocusignRESTContants.ENVELOPES );

        DocusignRESTClient client = (DocusignRESTClient) AppContext.getBean("restServiceClient");
        WebTarget resourceSendDocument = client.createResource( ESignatureSpringUtil.getMessage( KeyConstants.ALSB_DOCUSIGN_ADDRESS )
                + ESignatureSpringUtil.getMessage( KeyConstants.REST_SEND_DOCUMENTS_ADDRESS ) );

        resourceSendDocument.register(SendDocumentsServiceRequestXMLWriter.class);
        resourceSendDocument.register(SendDocumentsServiceResponseXMLReader.class);

        Invocation.Builder builder;


        Response response = resourceSendDocument.path( ESignatureSpringUtil.getMessage( KeyConstants.REST_SEND_DOCUMENTS_ADDRESS ) )
            .request()
            .header( KeyConstants.REST_URI_APPENDERS, docSb )
            .header( DocusignRESTContants.CONTENT_TYPE, DocusignRESTContants.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA )
            .header( DocusignRESTContants.X_DOCUSIGN_AUTHENTICATION, getDocusignAuthHeader( cu ) )
            .accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML )
            .post( Entity.entity( Response.class, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML ) );
            /*.accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML )
            .type( MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE )
            .post( Response.class, multiPart );*/

        if ( response.getStatus() == 200 ) {
            SendDocumentsResponse resp = response.readEntity( SendDocumentsResponse.class );

            envId = resp.getEnvelopeId();
            status = resp.getStatus();

            if( cu.getClient().getUsageType().getId().longValue() == Constants.USAGE_MODE_EMBEDDED ) {
                serviceName = "getToken";

                for (RecipientSigner signer : env.getRecipients().getSigners()) {
                    RecipientToken recipientToken = new RecipientToken();
                    recipientToken.setEmail(signer.getEmail());
                    recipientToken.setUserName(signer.getName());

                    if (null != signer.getClientUserId()) {
                        recipientToken.setClientUserId(signer.getClientUserId());
                    }
                    recipientToken.setRecipientId(signer.getRecipientId());

                    List<IClientUserPrefDto> pList = DtoUtils.getClientPrefenceByEntity(cu.getClientUserPref(), UserPreferencesConstants.CLIENT_PREF_ENT_CALLBACK_URL);
                    if (pList != null) {
                        for(Iterator<IClientUserPrefDto> listItr = pList.iterator();listItr.hasNext();) {
                            ClientUserPrefDto cup = (ClientUserPrefDto)listItr.next();
                            if(cup.getPrefAttrb().equalsIgnoreCase(CallbackConstants.SIGNING)) {
                                recipientToken.setReturnUrl(cup.getPrefValue());
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    OutputStream tokenStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    Marshaller jaxbTokenMarshal = context.getMarshaller(RecipientToken.class);
                    jaxbTokenMarshal.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
                    jaxbTokenMarshal.marshal(recipientToken, tokenStream);

                    StringBuilder tokenSb = new StringBuilder();
                    tokenSb.append( endpoint );
                    tokenSb.append( DocusignRESTContants.ACCOUNTS );
                    tokenSb.append( KeyConstants.URL_PATH_SEPARATOR );
                    tokenSb.append( accountId );
                    tokenSb.append( KeyConstants.URL_PATH_SEPARATOR );
                    tokenSb.append( DocusignRESTContants.ENVELOPES );
                    tokenSb.append( KeyConstants.URL_PATH_SEPARATOR );
                    tokenSb.append( envId );
                    tokenSb.append( KeyConstants.URL_PATH_SEPARATOR );
                    tokenSb.append( DocusignRESTContants.VIEWS );
                    tokenSb.append( KeyConstants.URL_PATH_SEPARATOR );
                    tokenSb.append( DocusignRESTContants.RECIPIENT );

                    WebTarget resourceGetToken = client.createResource( ESignatureSpringUtil.getMessage( KeyConstants.ALSB_DOCUSIGN_ADDRESS )
                            + ESignatureSpringUtil.getMessage( KeyConstants.REST_GET_TOKEN_ADDRESS) );

                    Response tokenResponse = resourceGetToken.request()
                        .header( KeyConstants.REST_URI_APPENDERS, tokenSb )
                        .header( DocusignRESTContants.CONTENT_TYPE, DocusignRESTContants.APPLICATION_XML )
                        .header( DocusignRESTContants.X_DOCUSIGN_AUTHENTICATION, getDocusignAuthHeader( cu ) )
                        /*.accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML )*/
                        /*.post( Response.class, new ByteArrayInputStream( tokenStream.toString().getBytes() ) );*/
                        .post( Entity.xml( new ByteArrayInputStream( tokenStream.toString().getBytes() ) ) );

                    if ( tokenResponse.getStatus() == 200 ) {
                        RetrieveTokenResponse tokenResp = (RetrieveTokenResponse) tokenResponse.readEntity(RetrieveTokenResponse.class);

                        token = tokenResp.getUrl();
                        String userName = recipientToken.getUserName();
                        for(IDocument doc:docs) {
                            DocuSignUtils.mapToken(doc, userName, token);
                        }
                    } else {
                        IClientUserPrefDto logPref = DtoUtils.getClientPrefenceByEntityAndAttribute(cu.getClientUserPref(), 
                            UserPreferencesConstants.CLIENT_PREF_ENT_MESSAGE_HANDLER, UserPreferencesConstants.CLIENT_PREF_ATTR_LOG_DOCUSIGN_REST_ERROR);
                        if (logPref != null && logPref.getPrefValue().equalsIgnoreCase(UserPreferencesConstants.CLIENT_PREF_VAL_YES)) {
                            getThreadLocal();
                            getEmailProcessor().processErrorMessage(response.readEntity(String.class), Constants.ESIGN_DOCUSIGN_REST_EMAIL_SUBJECT, cu, serviceName, envId);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            IDocumentSetTransactionDto dto = new DocumentSetTransactionDto(cu.getClientUserVendor().getId(), envId);            
            dto = DocusignRESTUtil.constructTransaction(dto, dtos, status, envId, token);
            getDocumentTransactionManager().create(cu, dto);

            List<IRecipientSigner> rtkns = new ArrayList<IRecipientSigner>();
            for(RecipientSigner signer : env.getRecipients().getSigners()) {
                IRecipientSigner rt = new com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.model.document.signer.RecipientSigner();
                rt.setEmail(signer.getEmail());
                rt.setName(signer.getName());
                rt.setRecipientId(signer.getRecipientId()+"");
                rtkns.add(rt);
            }
            IRecipientDocument recipientDoc = new RecipientDocument();
            recipientDoc.setIdentifier(envId);
            recipientDoc.setSigners(rtkns);
            getDocumentTransactionManager().createDocumentSetTransSigners(cu, dto, recipientDoc);

            IClientUserPrefDto pref = DtoUtils.getClientPrefenceByEntityAndAttribute(cu.getClientUserPref(), UserPreferencesConstants.CLIENT_PREF_ENT_TRACKING, UserPreferencesConstants.CLIENT_PREF_ATTR_ENABLED);
            if (pref != null && pref.getPrefValue().equalsIgnoreCase(UserPreferencesConstants.CLIENT_PREF_VAL_YES)) {
                getDocumentTransactionManager().createDocSetTransRecord(cu, dto, Boolean.TRUE);
            }
            set = new DocumentSet();
            set.setIdentifier(dto.getIdentifier());
            set.setToken(dto.getToken());
            set.setDocuments( DtoUtils.createSendDocumentsDocsList( docs, dto.getDocuments() ) );

            IClientUserPrefDto docPref = DtoUtils.getClientPrefenceByEntityAndAttribute(cu.getClientUserPref(), UserPreferencesConstants.CLIENT_PREF_ENT_ASYNC_PROCESSING, UserPreferencesConstants.CLIENT_PREF_ATTR_UNSIGNED_DOC_STORAGE);
            if (docPref != null && docPref.getPrefValue().equalsIgnoreCase(UserPreferencesConstants.CLIENT_PREF_VAL_YES)) {
                getDocumentArchiver().archieveUnsignedDocument(cu, set, docs);
            }

        } else {
            IClientUserPrefDto logPref = DtoUtils.getClientPrefenceByEntityAndAttribute(cu.getClientUserPref(), 
                UserPreferencesConstants.CLIENT_PREF_ENT_MESSAGE_HANDLER, UserPreferencesConstants.CLIENT_PREF_ATTR_LOG_DOCUSIGN_REST_ERROR);
            if (logPref != null && logPref.getPrefValue().equalsIgnoreCase(UserPreferencesConstants.CLIENT_PREF_VAL_YES)) { 
                getThreadLocal();
                getEmailProcessor().processErrorMessage(response.readEntity(String.class), Constants.ESIGN_DOCUSIGN_REST_EMAIL_SUBJECT, cu, serviceName, esignIdentifier);
            }
        }

    } catch (ProviderException e) {
        IExceptionHandlerResponse response = ExceptionHandler.instance().handleProvider(e, ProviderException.class);
        if (response.isRethrow()) {
            ProviderException pe = (ProviderException) response.getThrowable();
            throw pe;
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        IExceptionHandlerResponse response = ExceptionHandler.instance().handleProvider(t, ProviderException.class);
        if (response.isRethrow()) {
            ProviderException pe = (ProviderException) response.getThrowable();
            throw pe;
        }
    } finally {
        logMethodEndDebug(cu, CLASS_NAME, "sendDocuments(IClientUserDto, IDocumentSet)");   
    }

    return set;
}
```

pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version.no}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version.no}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version.no}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version.no}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version.no}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version.no}</version>
    </dependency>
```

stacktrace:

```
2017-03-27 09:22:41,037           com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.common.logging.LoggingHandler ERROR -   MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class  java.lang.Class, genericType=class java.lang.Class.
com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.service.ESignatureServiceException:  MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.lang.Class, genericType=class java.lang.Class.
at  org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:247)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.doWriteEntity(ClientRequest.java:517)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:499)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:393)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:437)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:343)
at com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.provider.docusign.rest.DocusignRESTProvider.sendDocuments(DocusignRESTProvider.java:320)
at  com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.controller.ESignatureController.sendDocuments(ESignatureController.java:87)
at  com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.service.ESignatureService.sendDocuments(ESignatureService.java:182)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.service.ESignatureServiceInterceptor.invoke(ESignatureServiceInterceptor.java:120)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.sendDocuments(Unknown Source)
at com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.client.rest.service.RestService.sendDocuments(RestService.java:257)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
at  org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at  org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.client.activity.ESignatureActivityTrackingFilter.doFilter(ESignatureActivityTrackingFilter.java:27)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by:   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.lang.Class, genericType=class java.lang.Class.
... 80 more
```

Comment: Have you added the `@XmlRootElement` annotation to your class?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: @ahoxha: I got all the annotations and i have this in my model. I've edited my question and added the code where the service breaks. Not sure if post method is being implemented correctly.

Comment: Can you make sure the service is responding correctly via another client, [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) for example?

Comment: I am using soapUi and same exception.

Comment: What's the exception? It seems like the server is throwing exceptions, it's not being able to return the correct result. Can you change the end-point?

Comment: Can you post the code that is returning the result and your model class?

Comment: The code you posted does _not_ match the error. Please post the _exact_ code for which you are getting the posted error

Comment: It breaks at post method, therefore I posted it here. I am not sure if I need to register the writer and reader classes?

Comment: @peeskillet. I've added the code.